# Why doesn't my function get called?

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am attempting to display a  ProgressDialog while I am loading a video. 
My play(String _videoUri) function doesn't seem to get called. 
Can anyone tell me why?

I have this exact same setup for starting a new Intent and it seems to work fine, but not in this case or loading a video from a given URL.

```
 private void showPopupMenu(View v){
   PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(VideoPlayer.this, v);


   if(bitRates != null){
          for(int i=0;i<bitRates.size();i++){
              int menuItem = i;
              popupMenu.getMenu().add(0,menuItem, 0,"BitRate: "+bitRates.get(i));

          }
      }
  popupMenu.show(); 
  popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

   public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem item) {
       progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(VideoPlayer.this, "", "Loading video...");
       new Thread() {

            public void run() {

                try{
                    play(streamUrls.get(item.getItemId())); 

                }
                catch (Exception e) 
                {

                    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());

                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }.start();

       return true;

   }
  });


 }


  public void play(String _videoUri){
         Log.i(TAG,"URI is : "+Uri.parse(_videoUri).toString());
         MediaController mc = new MediaController(VideoPlayer.this);
         mVideoView.setMediaController(mc); 
         mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(_videoUri));
         mVideoView.requestFocus();
         mVideoView.start();
  }
```

Comment: Try wrapping play() method call with runOnUiThread(Runnable action).

Comment: @yorkw thanks, that worked , but now the progressDialog isn't called at the correct time. It shows up after the video is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your anonymous thread in parentheses. 
    (new Thread() { ... }).start()

Comment: parentheses don't matter here